# Let $E$ Banach space, $\dim E = \infty$ and $T: E \longrightarrow E$ a linear isometry. Show that $T$ is not compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $E$ Banach space, $\dim E = \infty$ and $T: E \longrightarrow E$ a linear isometry. Show that $T$ is not compact.

**Comments:** I'm trying to solve it like this:

Suppose T is compact, then $\overline{T(B_E)}$ is compact. 
I can not use the fact that $T$ is linear isometry to prove that $B_E$ is compact and to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: $T(B) =B$. Is the unit ball in an infinite dimensional normed space every compact?

Comment: I do not know how to justify that $B_E \subset T(B_E)$.

Comment: $T$ is invertible.

Comment: To the other side, $\parallel Tx \parallel = \parallel x \parallel \leq 1 \Rightarrow  T(B_E) \subset B_E$

Comment: You need to do some work. If $T$ is invertible and $\|Tx\| = \|x\|$ then $\|T^{-1}x\| = \|x\|$ as well from which the other side follows.

Comment: @copper.hat The fact that $E$ is infinite dimensional means isometries need not be surjective.

Comment: I guess I need to do some work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $T$ is an isometry, the range $F$ of $T$ is closed, hence a Banach space.  Restricting the codomain to $F$, we obtain a bounded surjection, hence an open map.  But as $T$ is injective, $F$ is infinite-dimensional, hence it's closed unit ball is not compact.  But $T(B_E)=B_F$, so $T(B_E)$ is not compact, and therefore $T$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in the closed unit ball. Then $\{Tx_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence. The corresponding subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy, hence convergent. This makes the unit ball compact and the space finite dimensional.